# How do I find the error within this Fibonacci Sequence proof that is trying to prove that f(5) = 4?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

I am working on a problem in my textbook where I am given this proof dealing with Fibonacci numbers. The function $f$ is defined by $f(0) = f(1) = 1$ and for all $n\geq 2$, and $f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)$. The following proof is trying to prove $f(4) = 5$:

\begin{align*}
 f(4) &= 5\\
 f(3)+f(2) &= 5\\
 [f(2)+f(1)]+f(2) &= 5\\
 2f(2) + 1 &= 5\\
 2f(2) &= 4\\
 2(f(1) + f(0)) &= 4\\
 2(1+1) &= 4\\
 4 &= 4
\end{align*}

I know that this proof is incorrect, but I'm having a hard time finding how it is incorrect and coming up with sufficient reasoning. Every time I look at it, I can't seem to find a noticeable error. Can anyone give me some pointers and/or suggestions as to how this proof is incorrect? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The title of your question says $f(5)=4$ but the body says $f(4)=5$. In any case, why do you think the proof is incorrect? $f(0)=f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$, $f(3)=3$, $f(4)=5$.

Comment: @angryavian:  the problem is that the sequence definition does not match the usual Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ah, I remembered that the indexing started at zero, but mistakenly thought the first term was $1$ rather than $0$.

Comment: You should point out the conflict you see, that the usual Fibonacci sequence has $f(4)=3$.  Without that, there is no problem with the result.

Comment: It's true, isn't it? Except that you start from bottom to top : start with the true statement $4=4$ , go upwards in a series of implications, and reach $f(4) = 5$. And indeed, $f(4) = 5$ is true. In the title, $f(5) = 4$ is given. Please clarify : and there's no explicit mention of the Fibonacci sequence in your post, you may look up Wikipedia if necessary and mention if this result flusters you in any way , in relation to the Fibonacci sequence. The first answer seems to point this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is going in the wrong direction.  It starts with what it wants to prove and arrives at a truth.  As all the steps are reversible, that is not a problem this time.  It is bad practice because you have to commit to every step being reversible and people who check the proof have to be more careful.  That is not the root of the problem, which you do not state clearly.  The usual Fibonacci sequence has $f(4)=3$, which conflicts with the claimed result.

The real problem is in the definition of the Fibonacci sequence.  The usual definition is $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$.  The proof quotes a start that is off by $1$ from the usual definition.  Using the starting values given in the proof, the statement that $f(4)=5$ is correct.  It is just not the usual Fibonacci sequence.  I find it a good fake proof because people tend to overlook the starting values and concentrate on the algebra in the derivation.

Comment: Except in the question body it is not said that $f(n)$ is a Fibonacci sequence. It just so happens that it has the same recurrence formula as the Fibonacci sequence. And that the OP called it a Fibonacci sequence (when it's in fact not, at least in the ordinary sense). We actually don't know if the source material called that a Fibonacci sequence. To say the proof is invalid because of this is in a sense saying every proof about sequence that has the same reccurence formula as the Fibonacci sequence but not the same initial value is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your proof looks OK to me. But if you want a proof that ends with 5=5 then: 
 keep the first four steps; then replace f(2) with f(0)+f(1); then replace f(0) with 1 and replace f(1) with 1.

Comment: This misses the point.  We can also add one line where we add $1$ to each side and get $5=5$.  The problem is that for the usual Fibonacci sequence, $f(4)=3$